# Cannot read property 'result' of undefined IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, local-storage, indexeddb

I am trying to get the number likes from an IndexedDB database. However, I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined at IDBRequest.request.onsuccess

It is throwing the error on the line

> console.log(request.result)

```
parent.addEventListener('click', event => 
{
    //Get number of likes
    var transaction = db.transaction(['posts']);
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('posts');
    var request = objectStore.get(parseInt(event.target.id));

    request.onerror = function(event) 
    {
        console.log('Transaction failed');
    };

    request.onsuccess = function(event) 
   {
       console.log(request.result)
       if (request.result)
       {
            var nlikes = request.result.likes;
            console.log(request.result.text);
            nlikes + 1;

            //Increase the like of the post 
            var request = db.transaction(['posts'], 'readwrite')
                .objectStore('posts')
                .put({ id: parseInt(event.target.id),  likes: nlikes});

            request.onsuccess = function (event) 
            {
               console.log('The data has been updated successfully');
            };

            request.onerror = function (event) 
            {
                console.log('The data has been updated failed');

            //Add user like user to log
            }
       }     
   }
});
```

Comment: Are you familiar with basic javascript errors?

Comment: Please enlight me

Answer (score 3):

When debugging this error, it helps to be familiar with it. This error is a basic, general JavaScript error that does not apply to only indexedDB. The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined` occurs when you are trying to access a property of an uninitialized object. The uninitialized object in this case is the variable `request`, and the property is `result`. Therefore, understanding this error is a matter of understanding why `request` is undefined at the point in time when you try and access one of its properties.

I am not entirely certain why request is undefined without playing around with this code in a browser myself. However, I have a first guess that maybe will help you.

You declare again the same variable later in the function in the line `var request = db.transaction...`.  This might be the reason that the variable is undefined earlier in the function. I will try and explain why.

When you declare a variable with the `var` keyword, it does not always occur at the point where you declare it. When the JavaScript interpreter evaluates your code, it does a series of changes to it. One of the transformations that occurs is known as **hoisting**. Variables declare with `var` are hoisted to the beginning of the function, and/or in some cases even earlier and outside of the function scope. So, it is counter-intuitive, but the way the interpreter actually sees your code looks more like this:

```
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var request = undefined;
  console.log(request.result);
  if(request.result) {
     ...;
     request = db.transaction...;
     ...;
  }
};
```

As you can see in this variation of your code, request is clearly undefined by the time the console.log expression is evaluated.

How to fix this error? There are several ways.

First, consider using let/const instead of var. let/const are scope restricted. Think of scopes like the hierarchy of {} blocks. If you later declare request as `let request = ...` then this avoids the hoisting problem because `request` will not get hoisted outside of its enclosing {} block scope and therefore never jump up in evaluation order to the start of the ancestor function block scope.

Second, consider using a different variable. Instead of doing `var request = db.transaction...;` a second time, do `var request2 = db.transaction...;`. Now, hoisting still occurs, but this time the variable `request2` is hoisted to the top of the function, which does not have an identifier conflict with `request`. Now request will be defined at the time you call `console.log`.

Third, consider using one indexedDB transaction. You can issue multiple requests using a single transaction. It is not obvious from your code, but it looks like there is no good reason for you to be using separate transactions. The only reason I can think of might just be lack of familiarity with indexedDB. So it would help to learn how to issue multiple requests on a transaction. Also, in case it is a concern, using a single readwrite transaction will probably be faster than using one read followed by one write, if that was possibly your reason for multiple txns.

When you use multiple requests on a txn, now you will probably become interested in when the txn completes, instead of being interested in when the individual requests complete, and therefore, you no longer need to even declare the second request object, and therefore, no longer will run face first into the hoisting issue.

It would look something like this:

```
var txn = db.transaction(..., 'readwrite');
txn.oncomplete = function(event) {
  console.debug('txn completed');
};
txn.onerror = function(event) {
  console.debug('txn failed', event.target.error);
};

var store = txn.objectStore(...);
var request = store.get(...);
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  //...;
  store.put(...);
  //...;
};
```

In case it is not obvious, here I am just reusing store, which is an instance of an IDBObjectStore, which is still tied to the transaction in which it was created when I later call `store.put`.

Any one of these three different approaches will probably solve your problem.